# How do I animate height of list item upwards without screwing up the other list items?

Tags: html, css

I'm having a bit of a problem with this hover effect I'm trying to create in a menu. I simply want each box to move up a little when hovered over. From what I've produced, however, the height changes fine, but it takes all of the other a's in the list up with it. I want it to individually change height without moving the other menu items at all.

Does anyone have any advice as to what I should do to fix this?

I've tried doing the absolute positioning on the individual a's instead of on the ul, but that ruins the centering (all of the list items collapse into one another and I'm forced to have imprecise positioning that doesn't scale correctly with the browser.)

Thanks for your time and patience (I'm new at this, still learning.)

Here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/lhill86/Lnm6q0wy/) to demonstrate what I'm talking about.

Here's the markup:

```
<div class="navband">
   <div class="nav">
     <ul>
       <li><a href="#">Work</a></li>
       <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
       <li><a href="#">Blog</a></li>
       <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
     </ul>
   </div>
</div>
```

And the CSS:

```
.nav {
    text-align: center;
}

.nav ul {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
}

.nav ul li {
    list-style: none;
    display: inline;
    padding-left: 0.5em;
    padding-right: 0.5em;
}

.nav ul li a {
    display: inline-block;
    text-decoration: none;
    background: #F7941E;
    color: #414042;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    height: 130px;
    width: 120px;
}

.nav ul li a:hover {
    height: 150px;
}
```

Comment: You could have nested DIVs that take up the entire height and then verticaly align the inner divs to the top or bottom when hovered above, this would probably fix your issue.

Answer (score 1):

Here's what I came up with:

http://jsfiddle.net/lhill86/Lnm6q0wy/

Hope this helps

Added an aditonnal container:

```
<div class="navband">
   <div class="nav">
     <ul>
       <li><div class="nest"><a href="#">Work</a></div></li>
       <li><div class="nest"><a href="#">About</a></div></li>
       <li><div class="nest"><a href="#">Blog</a></div></li>
       <li><div class="nest"><a href="#">Contact</a></div></li>
     </ul>
   </div>
</div>
```

Here's the CSS:

```
.nav {
    text-align: center;
}

.nav ul {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    height:150px;
}

.nav ul li {
    list-style: none;
    display: inline-block;
    padding-left: 0.5em;
    padding-right: 0.5em;
    background:white;
    height:150px;
}

.nav ul li a {
    display: inline-block;
    text-decoration: none;
    background:#F7941E;
    color: #414042;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    height: 130px;
    width: 120px;
}
.nest{
    display:inline-block;
    margin-bottom:0px;
    height:130px;
    background-color: #F7941E;
}
.nest a:hover{
    height: 150px;
    margin-top:0px;
}
```

Edit: 
Sorry didn't post the latest version. But here is the final CSS that works:

```
.nav {
    text-align: center;
}

.nav ul {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    padding-bottom: 0px;
    margin-bottom:0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    height:150px;
}

.nav ul li {
    list-style: none;
    display: inline-block;
    padding-left: 0.5em;
    padding-right: 0.5em;
    background:white;
    height:150px;
}

.nav ul li a {
    display: inline-block;
    text-decoration: none;
    background:#F7941E;
    color: #414042;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    height: 130px;
    width: 120px;
}
.nest{
    display:inline-block;
    margin-bottom:0px;
    height:130px;
    background-color: #F7941E;
}
.nest a:hover{
    position:relative;
    top:-20px;
    height: 150px;
}
```

Comment: Sorry, first css I posted wasn't the final one, it had the the divs going down instead of up. But added the edit and everything works fine this way.

Answer (score 1):

Use padding instead like so:

```
.nav ul li a:hover {
padding-top:30px;
}
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/YoshiMaster/Lnm6q0wy/3/

Comment: Clearly the best answer, I would add in a `transition: padding-top 1.5s;` just to make it smooth, but that's a personal preference.

Comment: Yeah a transition would definitely spice it up.

Comment: I posted another answer the does similar, but the text actually moves up when you hover. This version doesn't move the text, so I guess it's a personal preference on the final look.

Comment: He didn't want them to line up with the active one, unless I read the post wrong.

Answer (score 1):

One idea to achieve this is, shifting the `margin-top` property.

Since you applied `display: inline` on `li`, `margin-top` and `margin-bottom` will not work on `a`. You can consider using `display: block` for `li` and float them to the left

```
.nav ul li {
    display: block;
    float: left;
}
```

Then set a margin-top to `a` and remove it on hover.

```
.nav ul li a {
    margin-top: 20px;
}

.nav ul li a:hover {
    margin-top: 0;
}
```

Thus you will get the desired output.

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/aniskhan001/Lh7bwr4x/)**

Comment: think he wanted the item to move up, but the others to stay down.

Comment: Thanks for replying! I did try this, but I need it to move up.